# python beautifulsoup crawler error while picking URL from mysql

Tags: python, mysql, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

i have one database where i have stored home page of some websites. I want this script to pickup one link from this database and then has to find other href links present on the page and then insert them in and other table in mysql. here is the script:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb
import os
import urllib2
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",
                 user="user",
                 passwd="password",
                 db="crw")
n = "no"
cat1 = "MOVIES"
cat2 = "NEWS"
loc  = "SL"
act = "YES"
cursor = conn.cursor()
ext1 = ("SELECT LINK FROM LINK_MASTER WHERE ACT = %s and CAT1 = %s AND CAT2 = %s AND LOC = %s")
cursor.execute(ext1, (act, cat1, cat2, loc))
urlq = cursor.fetchone()
url = urlq
print url
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "post-title"}):
    for link in item.find_all('a'):
        p = (link.get('href'))
        print p
        cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO URL(URL,FD,CAT1,CAT2) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)", (p,n,cat1,cat2))
        conn.commit()
```

I am getting following error. Please help me in resolving this, as i am new to python and trying to learn new stuff.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "news.py", line 25, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 428, in request
    env_proxies = get_environ_proxies(url) or {}
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 516, in get_environ_proxies
    if should_bypass_proxies(url):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/utils.py", line 478, in should_bypass_proxies
    netloc = urlparse(url).netloc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 143, in urlparse
    tuple = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 182, in urlsplit
    i = url.find(':')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Comment: Find out (debug?) the value of `url` when the exception occur... it might gives a hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url is in the *tuple* returned from fetchone, you need to pass that to requests not the tuple itself:

```
url = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```